# can't write in arabic in an html page with utf encoding in distant server

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, arabic

I'm writing a website in arabic,I use utf8 as charset,when I test it under wamp,it's ok I can read the arabic,but when I've uploaded it to kilu.com-you can see it at http://ajial.co.nu  I can't read it,and all the text changes into characters that I can't read.please help me if anyone has an answer to this.

Comment: You'll probably need to run it through a converter into HTML entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your script, someplace before it produces any output:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Currently the website emits this header which may confuse some web browsers.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: That should do, because manually changing encoding in browser fixes the web page.